# Replace beginning words

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the below  tables.

**tblInput**

```
Id  WordPosition    Words
--  -----------     -----
1   1               Hi
1   2               How
1   3               are
1   4               you
2   1               Ok
2   2               This
2   3               is
2   4               me
```

**tblReplacement**

```
Id  ReplacementWords
--- ----------------
1   Hi
2   are
3   Ok
4   This
```

The `tblInput` **holds the list of words** while the `tblReplacement` **hold the words 
that we need to search in the tblInput** and if a match is found then we need to replace 
those.

But the problem is that, we need to replace those words if  any match is found at the beginning.

i.e. in the tblInput,

**in case of ID 1**, the words that will be replaced is only `'Hi'` `and not 'are'`

since before 'are', 'How' is there  and it is not in the tblReplacement list.

**in case of Id 2,** the words that will be replaced are `'Ok' & 'This'`. Since these both

words are present in the tblReplacement table and after the first word i.e. **'Ok'** is

replaced, the second word which is **'This'** here comes first in the list of

**ID category 2**

. Since it is available in the tblReplacement, and is the first word now, so this will

also be replaced.

So the desired output will be

```
Id  NewWordsAfterReplacement
--- ------------------------
1   How
1   are
1   you 
2   is
2   me
```

My approach so far:

```
;With Cte1 As(
Select 
    t1.Id
    ,t1.Words
    ,t2.ReplacementWords
From tblInput t1 
Cross Join tblReplacement t2)
,Cte2 As(
Select Id, NewWordsAfterReplacement = REPLACE(Words,ReplacementWords,'')
From Cte1)

Select * from Cte2 where NewWordsAfterReplacement <> ''
```

But I am not getting the desired output. It is replacing all the matching words.

Urgent help needed**.( SET BASED )**

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Thanks

Comment: You've been asking this question or slight variations thereof over and over again.... I'm almost inclined to close as duplicate. Also: you're dealing with **string manipulation** - this is **NOT** something you can do in a set-based manner - you need to fiddle around with strings - there's nothing set-based about that (and no way to do this "set-based"). Using the CTE (WITH.....) is about as set-based as you can be - so again: what on earth do you **REALLY** want???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt exactly understand your requirement.But from what I understand this works for the given data

```
with cte1 as(
select 1 as id,   1 as wp, 'Hi' as words union all
select 1,  2       ,        'How' union all
select 1 ,  3   ,            'are' union all
select 1 ,  4   ,            'you' union  all
select 2 ,  1       ,        'Ok' union all
select 2 ,  2 ,              'This' union all
select  2 ,  3   ,            'is' union all
select 2 ,  4       ,        'me'
),
 cte2 as(
select 1 as id,  'Hi' as rep union all
select 2 ,  'are' union all
select 3 ,  'Ok' union all
select 4  , 'This')

select ID,words from cte1
except
select ID,words from(
select a.id,a.words,a.wp,RANK() over(partition by a.id order by wp) as rnk
from cte1 as a inner join
cte2 as b on a.words=b.rep
) as x
where x.wp=x.rnk
```

Comment: then the solution that i have proposed should work- you will need to change column names etc